# Netsuite USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error on suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have created a suitelet script in which the line items in assembly build are set in the suitelet multiplied by quantity. i.e. if there is quantity 2 then two lines will be setting in suitelet for that item. suitelet opens by clicking save.

The problem is if there are more items in the assembly build then suitelet wont open and throws the error USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED.

I tried to reduce the script code but it didnt help

```
var b=0;var nItemLinesCount = objRecord.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'component' }); for(var i=0; i<nItemLinesCount; i++)                                          
{

  if(Qty > 0)
  {
    for(j=0; j<Qty; j++)
    {
      sublist.setSublistValue({
      id : 'custpage_item',
      line : b,
      value : nItem
     });
       sublist.setSublistValue({
      id : 'custpage_qty',
      line : b,
      value : '1'
      }); b++;
    }
  }                                                                         
}
```

Comment: You're not showing enough code for anyone to help. Even in the code you pasted you don't show how `Qty` is set.

Comment: You're getting this error because your script is running out of governance units. If you're not familiar with NetSuite's governance system, you can brush up here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTRim5Ed8Yo

Comment: I am getting Qty from the component sublist and setting as 1 in suitelet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each SuiteScript has a "usage limit" (sometimes called a governance unit).

The way to work around this is to check much usage is left using `nlapiGetContext().getRemainingUsage()` and if the number is lower than what you'll expect to use in the next loop in your script, reschedule the script to run again later.

You'll need to design your script deterministically. You need to be able to run the script multiple times without it creating any sort of duplicate data or results. If you design your script in this fashion, then rescheduling the SuiteScript to run when usage is low won't create any unintended side effect.

Here's an example:

https://gist.github.com/iloveitaly/eb3fffa67c5ea08010d3de6e552f84d3

Specifically, check out the `isScriptUsageRemaining` and `rescheduleScript` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a false positive if you don't have scripting enabled in your company.